# Merge Dictionaries Based on Matching Values from 2 Specified Keys [Matching Values are in Numpy Arrays]

Tags: python, numpy

Been looking around, but haven't yet found a solution to this. Sorry if I missed it.

I'm trying to create the equivalent of a pandas merge or SQL JOIN with dictionaries where the values are numpy arrays.

Below is an example input / what the desired goal is.

**Ex Inputs**:

```
import numpy as np
dict_1 = {
    'col1': np.array(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']), 
    'col2': np.array(['item1', 'item2', 'item3','item4'])}
dict_2 = {
    'col3': np.array(['two', 'two', 'six', 'seven', 'eight']), 
    'col4': np.array(['item2', 'item3','item4','item5','item 5'])}
```

~**Ex Desired Output (UPDATED)**:  ~

```
new_dict = {
    'col1': array(['one', 'two', 'two', 'two', 'three', 'four']),
    'col2': array(['item1', 'item2', 'item2','item3','item3','item4']),
    'col3': array([np.nan, 'two', 'two', np.nan, np.nan]),
    'col4': array([np.nan, 'item2', 'item3', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]),
}
```

So the goal here is that the function would identify matches between `col1` in `dict_1` and `col3` in `dict_2` then return all matches with the priority being on the left side.

i.e., priority being on left side == `four` is returned as it's in `dict_1` even though there is no match - similar like you'd see on:

1. a pandas merge `how='left'` on 2 DataFrames
2. a LEFT JOIN in sql on two database tables

Of course I could turn the dictionaries into DataFrames and use pandas merge, but ideally looking to solve for this without using pandas.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Thank you

**Here's how to accomplish desired result with Pandas Merge**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dict_1 = {
    'col1': np.array(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']), 
    'col2': np.array(['item1', 'item2', 'item3','item4'])}
dict_2 = {
    'col3': np.array(['two', 'two', 'six', 'seven', 'eight']), 
    'col4': np.array(['item2', 'item3','item4','item5','item 5'])}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict_1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict_2)

new_df = df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on='col1', right_on='col3')
new_df
```

Comment: Could you, please, show how you would use [pandas.Dataframe.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to get the desired output from your example.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Too late in the night, and realizing I made a mistaken in the expected output. Will update now

Looking for something like new_df = df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on='col1', right_on='col3')

Comment: @Bob - sorry about that. Updated the post to show correct output + how to accomplish the same general thing using pandas merge.

Comment: And you want all the four columns? Do you intend to use it to large arrays or only small (say <100 rows).

Comment: @Bob - yes, I need all columns returned ideally. The arrays will be fairly sizeable (upwards of ~10k values within an array on some of the largest use cases - but generally will be more like 500 - 1000 values per array).

Answer (score 0):

Ended up figuring out how to do this (not 1:1 matching the above req - but similar / gets to same desired output).

Definitely not the cleanest solution in the world (not even close), but it gets the job done...

Here's the final script:

```
import numpy as np
import sm_pandas as spd

struct_arr1 = np.array([('jason', '28', 'j@j.com', 'j@j.com'), ('jared', '31', 'jm@j.com', 'j@j.com'),('george', '28', 'gmm@j.com', 'j@j.com')],
           dtype=[('name', 'object'), ('ag', 'object'), ('emai', 'object'), ('email', 'object')])

struct_arr2 = np.array([('jason', '22', 'jm@j.com'), ('jason', '27', 'jmm@j.com'), ('jared', 22, 'm@j.com')],
           dtype=[('name', 'object'), ('age', 'object'), ('email', 'object')])

def removeDuplicates(lst):
      
    return [t for t in (set(tuple(i) for i in lst))]


def join_by_left(key, r1, r2):
    # figure out the dtype of the result array
    key1 = r1.dtype.descr
    list_keys1 = [d[0] for d in key1]
    
    key2 = r2.dtype.descr
    list_keys2 = [d[0] for d in key2]

    len_keys = len(list_keys1)

    # get a dict of the rows of r2 grouped by key
    rows2 = {}
    for row2 in r2:
        rows2.setdefault(row2[key], []).append(row2)

    # merge the data into the return array
    new_arr = []
    for row1 in r1:
        if row1[key] in rows2: # return matching on key
            for row2 in rows2[row1[key]]:
                ret = tuple(row1[list_keys1]) + tuple(row2[list_keys2])
                new_arr.append(ret)

        else: # for left join to return non-matches on left side
            for j in range(len_keys):
                null = ('na','na','na')
                ret = tuple(row1[list_keys1]) + tuple(null)
                new_arr.append(ret)

    new_arr = removeDuplicates(lst=new_arr) # remove any duplicates

    return new_arr

new_arr = join_by_left(key='name', r1=struct_arr1, r2=struct_arr2)

# convert to list of lists
final = []
r = len(new_arr[0])
for num in range(r):
    fields = [i[num] for i in new_arr]
    final.append(fields)

# convert list of lists to dict
new_dict = {}
i=1
for item in final:
    ndict = {f'field{i}': np.array(item)}
    new_dict.update(ndict)
    i = i + 1

print(new_dict)
```

**Returns**

```
{
    'field1': array(['jared', 'jason', 'george', 'jason'], dtype='<U6'), 
    'field2': array(['31', '28', '28', '28'], dtype='<U2'), 
    'field3': array(['jm@j.com', 'j@j.com', 'gmm@j.com', 'j@j.com'], dtype='<U9'), 
    'field4': array(['j@j.com', 'j@j.com', 'j@j.com', 'j@j.com'], dtype='<U7'), 
    'field5': array(['jared', 'jason', 'na', 'jason'], dtype='<U5'), 
    'field6': array(['22', '27', 'na', '22'], dtype='<U11'), 
    'field7': array(['m@j.com', 'jmm@j.com', 'na', 'jm@j.com'], dtype='<U9')
}
```